# how to handle forms in multiple pages?

Tags: forms

I have a simple contact form that I set up to display on multiple pages using a shortcode and a widget but since I need to form to post back on the same were it's displayed I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I was thinking about writing a function and plug it to the `wp_head` hook but I'm not sure if it's correct, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of - I would suggest using `init`. This would probably be the best way of doing it since you can process the form as described below. `wp_head` would work though. Also, you should make sure you are making necessary checks with 'nonces'.

I suggest the `init` hook as you can employ something similar to 'post-redirect-get' (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)). This can help against resubmission of data when users click refresh. The usual way of doing this is to submit the url of the page along with the form, submit to a processing page, which when it's finished then redirects the user back to the original page (or a confirmation page).

Of course you don't need a separate 'processing page'. An action hooked onto `init` can check a form is submitted, check the nonces, process the form and then redirect back to the page.

Comment: That sounds good, I was wondering how to handle form resubmission too, using `init` would be better since headers haven't already been sent at this point right?

Comment: Yup, you wouldn't able to do that with wp_head